# use sql selected values as row names for another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a MSSQL server, given the tables:

```
TABLE values {
    int id;
    timestamp date;
    int value;
}

TABLE value_type {
    int value_id; // foreign key on values.id
    text name;
}
```

I can issue a query like:

```
SELECT date, name, value
FROM values
LEFT JOIN value_type ON value_id = id;
```

and get something like:

```
+----------+------+-------+
| date     | name | value |
+----------+------+-------+
| 01.01.10 | foo  |  1.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
| 01.01.10 | bar  |  2.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
| 02.01.10 | bar  |  4.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
| 03.01.10 | foo  |  5.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
```

What's the most efficient way to query the database if I'd like to get the data like this?

```
+----------+------+-------+
| date     | foo  | bar   |
+----------+------+-------+
| 01.01.10 | 1.0  |  2.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
| 02.01.10 | NULL |  4.0  |
+----------+------+-------+
| 03.01.10 | 5.0  |  NULL |
+----------+------+-------+
```

The database structure is a lot more complicated, and unfortunately I can't change it.

**EDIT**: The solution should not use `foo` and `bar` as hardcoded values in the query.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can use dynamic SQL and `PIVOT`.

```
DECLARE @ValuesNames NVARCHAR(4000), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ValuesNames = ''

SELECT @ValuesNames = @ValuesNames + QUOTENAME([name]) + ','
FROM [values] A
INNER JOIN value_type B
ON B.value_id = A.id
GROUP BY [name]
ORDER BY [name]

SET @ValuesNames = LEFT(@ValuesNames,LEN(@ValuesNames)-1)

SET @Query = '
SELECT [date], '+@ValuesNames+'
FROM (  SELECT [date], [name], value
        FROM [values]
        LEFT JOIN value_type ON value_id = id) A
PIVOT(SUM(value) FOR [name] IN ('+@ValuesNames+')) AS PT
'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Beautiful, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I seem to fail to run SELECT @foo = @foo + field FROM ..., SELECT @foo = field FROM ... works, but of course I'll onl get the last row. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, there were some NULL values in the table, fixed it. I'll accept yours for showing the usage of PIVOT.

Answer (score 2):

You could `group by` on Date:

```
SELECT  Date
,       max(case when vt.name = 'foo' then v.value end) as Foo
,       max(case when vt.name = 'bar' then v.value end) as Bar
FROM Values v
LEFT JOIN 
        value_type vt
ON      vt.value_id = v.id
group by
        Date
```

By the way, the foreign key seems unusual.  I'd expect a `value_type` column in the `values` table, not a `value_id` column in the `values_type` table!  There are a lot more values than value types, right?

EDIT: There is no way in SQL to generate a variable number of columns, so you'll have to resort to meta-SQL, or dynamic SQL.  Here's an example:

```
create table [values] (id int, date datetime, value float)
insert [values] values (1, '2010-01-01', 1.0)
insert [values] values (2, '2010-01-01', 2.0)
insert [values] values (3, '2010-01-02', 4.0)
insert [values] values (4, '2010-01-03', 5.0)
create table value_types (value_id int, name varchar(max))
insert value_types values (1,'foo'), (2,'bar'), (3,'bar'), (4,'foo')

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ''
select  @sql = @sql + ',       max(case when vt.name = ''' + 
                   name + ''' then v.value end) as ' + name + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
from    value_types
group by
        name

set @sql = 'SELECT  Date
' + @sql + 
'FROM   [values] v
LEFT JOIN 
        value_types vt
ON      vt.value_id = v.id
group by
        Date'

exec (@sql)
```

This prints:

```
Date        bar     foo
----------- ------- -------
2010-01-01  2       1
2010-01-02  4       NULL
2010-01-03  NULL    5
```

Comment: Unfortunately hardcoding the value names in the example is not an option. I edited my question.

Comment: That looks great! I'll try it out tomorrow and will accept it if I can make it work.

Comment: I seem to fail to run SELECT @foo = @foo + field FROM ..., SELECT @foo = field FROM ... works, but of course I'll onl get the last row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on new requirements:
You will need to either dynamically generate the SQL statement for the query or if you are loading it into your application you could transform the data from your original query or a similar query.

Comment: Looks like you think each value has a reference to a value_type, but it's the other way around: each value_type has a reference to the value it belongs to.  So you'll need a join to value type in both parts of your full join.

Comment: Please see my last edit: harcoding foo and bar is not an option.

Comment: @chris, in that case you are going to have to dynamically create the statement.

Answer (score 0):

untested: you could define a view to join the tables on the pk-fk pair, and then try something like this:

```
Select date, 

case name when "foo" then value else null end as foo, 

case name when "base" then value else null end as bar 

from mytable  

order by date
```

Here you need to know the range of possible values in advance.

TO make it more flexible, you could build a dynamic case statement from the distinct values of "name" in a stored procedure and call exec() on this string.

Comment: Please see my last edit: harcoding foo and bar is not an option.

Comment: I'd build a stored procedure to iterate through all distinct values of column "NAME", ("create #temptable as select distinct name from values") build a long sql string in a cursor loop, finally execute the query using exec().  maybe a search for "crosstab and sql" will help you find more answers on this site. the problem has quite a number of variations.

Comment: could you edit your answer and show how to do this? I'm no SQL expert and don't understand your comment :(

Comment: user lamak has already answered the question with a very similar  (and better) strategy as I proposed,. A few statements in a batch (you can wrap it in a create procedure stmt), build a long string @query, then sp_executesql( @query )