# Combining SQL Server lookup data using query results as tables to search

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Lookup` that defines connections between `Users`, `Groups` and `Apps`:

aLookup:

```
+----+---------+-------+-----------+---------+
| id | from_id | to_id | from_type | to_type |
+====+=========+=======+===========+=========+
|  1 |    1    |   2   |    User   |  Group  |
+----+---------+-------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |    2    |   1   |    Group  |   App   |
+----+---------+-------+-----------+---------+

 aUser                      aGroup          aApp
+----+---------+--------+  +----+-------+  +----+-----------+--------+
| id |  F_Name | L_Name |  | id |  Name |  | id |    Name   |   url  |
+====+=========+========+  +====+=======+  +====+===========+========+
|  1 |  Foobar | Whatley|  |  1 |   Sys |  |  1 | TPS_Admin | /tpsa/ |
+----+---------+--------+  +----+-------+  +----+-----------+--------+
|  2 |   Turd  |Ferguson|  |  2 |  Mgmt |  |  2 |     TPS   |  /tps/ |
+----+---------+--------+  +----+-------+  +----+-----------+--------+
```

The `Lookup` table grants `Users` access to `Applications` via `Groups`.

I want to use `from_type` & `to_type` as the tables to search.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    l.id, X.Name AS from_name, Y.Name AS to_name
FROM 
    aLookup l
LEFT JOIN 
    ["a" + l.from_type] X ON l.from_id = X.id
LEFT JOIN 
    ["a" + l.to_type] Y ON l.to_id = Y.id
```

Ideally it would produce something like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |   from_name  | to_name |
+====+==============+=========+
|  1 |Foobar Whatley|   Mktg  |
+----+--------------+---------+
|  1 |     Mktg     |   TPS   |    
+----+--------------+---------+
```

I have checked out [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785322/use-sql-selected-values-as-row-names-for-another-select) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083647/dynamical-ms-sql-query) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067472/dynamic-sql-query-search) already, but they seem to deal more with combining data down to a single entity; like the number of items sold on a certain date. Whereas I need something that sandwiches data together.

Here's some things to keep in mind:

- I realize there will have to be some conditional logic to handle the User's First & Last names into just 'Name', but I'm not sure what that looks like.
- I can change any of the table structures, ***nothing is set in stone yet***. So if you think there's a better way to do the whole thing, let me know.
- I am using Code Behind(C#) to develop this, so that's also a possibility although I would like to keep the connections to the db to a minimum.

Comment: For your first bullet point, I woudl use a persisted computed field that creates the whole name. Then you only have to create the formula once and you can use it all throgh the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of left joining to the tables in question and then picking what to display with a CASE.

```
select id,
  CASE WHEN from_type = 'User' THEN UserFrom.F_Name + ' ' + UserFrom.L_Name 
       WHEN from_type = 'Group' THEN GroupFrom.Name
       ELSE '<unknown>' END as from_name,
  CASE WHEN to_type = 'App' THEN AppTo.Name
       WHEN to_type = 'Group' THEN GroupFrom.Name
       ELSE '<unknown>' END as to_name
from aLookup L
left join aUser UserFrom on L.from_id = UserFrom.id
left join aGroup GroupFrom on L.from_id = GroupFrom.id
left join aGroup GroupTo on L.to_id = GroupFrom.id
left join aApp AppTo on L.to_id = AppTo.id
```

If you have more types just add in more joins and cases to the CASE statements.

Comment: I really like the simplicity. I was hoping for something a little more dynamic, but this is great for readability. Thanks!

Comment: @TravisHeeter - Well this can easily be the basis for a dynamic query -- just dynamically create the joins and the case statements.

Answer (score 0):

How did you come up with such a strange way to do this?
I would do something like this:

*Entity tables:*

- TblGroups:
  Group_Id int
  Group_Name varchar(50) -- or whatever number suits your needs
- TblApps
  App_Id int
  App_Name varchar(50) -- or whatever number suits your needs
- TblUsers
  User_Id int
  User_UserName varchar(20)
  User_Password varchar(10) -- **Don't forget to encrypt it!!!**
  Other User details such as user first and last name and whatever...

*connection tables:*

- TblUserToGroup
  UTG_UserId int
  UTG_GroupId int
- TblGroupToApp
  GTA_GroupId int
  GTA_AppId int

I guess I don't have to tell you what indexes to use, but if I do just leave a comment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: To answer your question: 'How did I come up with this?': scalability and flexibility. For instance if I wanted to assign a `User` directly to an `App`, or if I wanted to add a `Role` table to the mix.

Comment: I thoght that groups are roles... I don't see the advantage of the structure you suggested. You could connect a role in both structures, asign them to gropus or users. I also don't see the  advantage your desired outcome. Correct me if I'm wrong but this should be for authenticating users, right? (Writing from a cellphone, forgive my spelling...)

Comment: My goal is to organize Users and allow them to use Applications, not to authenticate. OK, so Roles vs Groups: As one gets more applications to support, access starts growing and overlapping. It's much easier to define a Role that is a member of Groups than it is to define a specific Group for each Person. Like if Sally gets promoted or demoted we'd have to change all her Groups, but if there were already 2 or 3 Roles, it would be an easy switch. Of course if you have too few Apps and Users this is overkill and confusing, but it's always good to plan for a future you can't imagine.

Comment: I've used the design i suggested for a system of 300 users and about a 100 forms. It' working

Comment: I've used the system you've described too.